# jquery selectable mousedown unselecting metakey

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying to get selectable working for a mobile app (using jquery mobile).   Everything works well if I use the control mousedown to select single additions (and to do unselects).

But since it is for a mobile app I can't use the control key.   I have added this code to handle the control key .. and it works to add selection events, but it breaks the unselecting of selected events.  (I.e. if you click on selected item it does not un-select).   Also for some reason this hangs up after a while and gets very slow processing the events...

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
  $("#tableId").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable();
```

My full set of code is in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y3TUj/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on mobile, why don't use a `tap` to select and unselect (instead of `metakey`)...?

Try this:

```
    $("#tableId").bind("tap", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var el = e.target;
        if ($(el).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
           $(el).removeClass('ui-selected').addClass('ui-unselecting');
        } else {
           $(el).addClass("ui-selecting");
        }
        $("#tableId").data("ui-selectable")._mouseStop(null);
   });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xw16e2ks/1/

Comment: Thank you for responding.   The problem with this is that the tap unselects all previous selections.   I am trying to set it up so that the previous selections only unselect if that cell is mousedown'ed on...

Comment: @user2040850: did you tried my example? `e.preventDefault();` should avoid that.

Comment: Yes.   From the desktop, when I tried it, a click on a 2nd cell deselected the previous cell and clicking on a selected cell did not deselect that cell

Comment: @user2040850: from the Desktop the standard behavior with the lasso selection still remains the same, as the built-in in the selectable. But: if you try with Chrome and select the option Mobile from developer tools, then you will see the Tap event will be raised, and the behavior will be the Mobile standard, i.e. Tap to select any you want, Tap to deselect any you want. This was the reason of my proposal, because a Mobile lasso selection may be result in a swipe.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. This is what I need for mobile.     My one question is is there any way to get the desktop rubber-banding (what you call lasso??) working where you make a second selection and it keeps the previous values selected?  ... For now I am doing two separate pages for desktop and mobile so it is not a problem using different scripts...but it would be nice.

Comment: @user2040850: i understand your primary need, so my answer is just only an alternative proposal - BTW: i don't think you would need two separate pages: think for example: what shall be with modern laptops, with mousepad  and touch screen? There should work both methods. Your main question: yes, it's possible, but my guess is, it would be easier to implement a custom rubber band than customize the selectable, just my opinion.

Comment: You are most likely correct... But I will have to have separate pages for other reasons .. the Desktop and the mobile will be to entirely different pages so the solution you gave is what I need... I was just curious about why desktop did work ... again thanks for the help.